# Set two canvas squares to the center of a canvas with HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, centering

I have two boxes positioned on a canvas that I am trying to center. You can view this on JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FVU47/5/

My canvas has 1000 height and 1000 width as follows:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="1000" height="1000" style="border:3px solid #385D8A; outline:1px solid #7592B5; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; background-color: #B9CDE5"></canvas>
```

I am then attempting to center the two boxes with the following code, which would place either box1 or box2 in the center of the canvas, depending on whether I click on "Go to Box 1" or "Go to Box 2" (see the bottom of the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FVU47/5/) Result quadrant:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#box1click").click(function(){
    if (rect1.x <= 500) {
      positionWidthSet = Math.abs(rect1.x - canvas.width/2) + rect1.x;
    }
    else{
      positionWidthSet = Math.abs(Math.abs(rect1.x - canvas.width/2) + rect1.x)
    }
    if (rect1.y >= 500) {
      positionHeightSet = Math.abs(rect1.y -canvas.height/2);
    }
    else{
      positionHeightSet = Math.abs(Math.abs(rect1.y - canvas.height/2) + rect1.y);
    }

    positionCanvasContext(positionWidthSet,positionHeightSet);
  });
});


$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#box2click").click(function(){
     if (rect2.x <= 500) {
      positionWidthSet = Math.abs(rect2.x - canvas.width/2) + rect2.x;
    }
    else{
      positionWidthSet = Math.abs(Math.abs(rect2.x - canvas.width/2) + rect2.x)
    }
    if (rect2.y >= 500) {
      positionHeightSet = Math.abs(rect2.y -canvas.height/2);
    }
    else{
      positionHeightSet = Math.abs(Math.abs(rect2.y - canvas.height/2) + rect2.y);
    }

    positionCanvasContext(positionWidthSet,positionHeightSet);
  });
});
```

Currently, clicking on either "Go to Box 1" or "Go to Box 2" does not center the canvas around either Box 1 or Box 2, even though experimenting with my formulas in the console would seem to indicate otherwise.

Comment: Why do you have 2 `document.ready` functions right next to eachother? jQuery-ers... I tell ya...

Comment: My comments on this matter far exceed the scope of this question. I'd have you join me in chat, but I've been banned for a day, lol

Comment: I've reduced it to one `document.ready`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/GpMsk/

**Put all your rects in an array:**

```
var rects=[];

rects.push({
  x: 103,
  y: 262,
  w: 200,
  h: 100,
  fillStyle: 'red',
  hovered: false
});

rects.push({
  x: 484,
  y: 170,
  w: 200,
  h: 100,
  fillStyle: 'blue',
  hovered: false
});
```

**Create a draw() function that draws all rects in the rects[] array**

Draw all rects with a specified x/y offset to their original x/y:

```
function draw(offsetX,offsetY){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    for(var i=0;i<rects.length;i++){
        var r=rects[i];
        ctx.fillStyle=r.fillStyle;
        ctx.fillRect(r.x+offsetX,r.y+offsetY,r.w,r.h);
    }
}
```

**When you click a button, calculate the offsets necessary to pull the specified rectangle to the center of the canvas**

Then redraw all rects with the calculated offsets.

```
var centerX=canvas.width/2;
var centerY=canvas.height/2;

function centerThisRect(rectsIndex){
    var r=rects[rectsIndex];
    var offsetX=centerX-r.x-r.w/2;
    var offsetY=centerY-r.y-r.h/2;
    draw(offsetX,offsetY);
}
```

Comment: Perfect @markE . I was able to mold the fiddle code you gave to my own using just the function centerThisRect function. See the code: http://jsfiddle.net/FVU47/9/